# Get modified line numbers in javascript github action

Tags: javascript, typescript, github-actions, pull-request

I'm trying to write a JavaScript (in TypeScript) Github Action to check the code change in a Pull Request. I managed to get the names of the modified files by doing this:

```js
import * as github from '@actions/github';
import * as core from '@actions/core';

async function run() {
  const base = github.context.payload.pull_request.base.sha;
  const head = github.context.payload.pull_request.head.sha;

  const client = github.getOctokit(core.getInput('token', {required: true});
  const response = await client.repos.compareCommits({
    base,
    head,
    owner: context.repo.owner,
    context.repo.repo,
  });

  const files = response.data.files;
  const fileNames = files.map((file) => file.filename);
}

run ();
```

I also would like to know what lines are modified (only the lines of the head files are fine), but it doesn't seem to be accessible from `files`, and I am a bit stuck.

For information, the type of `files` is:

```js
{
    sha: string;
    filename: string;
    status: string;
    additions: number;
    deletions: number;
    changes: number;
    blob_url: string;
    raw_url: string;
    contents_url: string;
    patch?: string | undefined;
    previous_filename?: string | undefined;
}[]
```

How can I get the line numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it.
`.patch` contains the changes of the file and is usually constructed as following

```js
"@@ -6,7 +6,9 @@ <fileCodeChanges> @@ -12,7 +12,3 <fileCodeChanges2> ..."
```

All the changes are separeted by

```js
`@@ -${startLineDeletion},${numberOfDeletion} +${startLineAddition},${numberOfAddition} @@`
```

So I just have to

1. Split `.patch` with `"@@"`
2. Filter the code parts to keep only the line numbers
3. Extract the numbers

Here is my code:

```js
import * as github from '@actions/github';
import * as core from '@actions/core';

interface FileLines {
  start: number;
  end: number
}

export interface ModifiedFile {
  name: string;
  deletion?: FileLines[];
  addition?: FileLines[];
}


async function run() {
  const base = github.context.payload.pull_request.base.sha;
  const head = github.context.payload.pull_request.head.sha;

  const client = github.getOctokit(core.getInput('token', {required: true});
  const response = await client.repos.compareCommits({
    base,
    head,
    owner: context.repo.owner,
    context.repo.repo,
  });

  const files = response.data.files;
  const modifiedFilesWithModifiedLines = files.map(parseFile);
}

function parseFile(file: {filename: string, patch?: string|undefined}): ModifiedFile {
  const modifiedFile: ModifiedFile = {
    name: file.filename
  };
  if (file.patch) {
    // The changes are included in the file
    const patches = file.patch.split('@@').filter((_, index) => index % 2); // Only take the line information and discard the modified code
    for (const patch of patches) {
      // patch is usually like " -6,7 +6,8"
      try {
        const hasAddition = patch.includes('+');
        const hasDeletion = patch.includes('-');
        if (hasAddition) {
          const lines = patch.match(/\+.*/)![0].trim().slice(1).split(',').map(num) => parseInt(num)) as [number, number];
          modifiedFile.addition ??= [];
          modifiedFile.addition?.push({
            start: lines[0],
            end: lines[0] + lines[1],
          });
        }
        if (hasDeletion) {

          const lines = patch.split('+')[0].trim().slice(1).split(',').map((num) => parseInt(num)) as [number, number];
          modifiedFile.deletion ??= [];
          modifiedFile.deletion?.push({
            start: lines[0],
            end: lines[0] + lines[1],
          });
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error getting the patch of the file:\n${error}`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Take the all file
    modifiedFile.addition = [{
        start: 0,
        end: Infinity,
    }];
    modifiedFile.deletion = [{
        start: 0,
        end: Infinity,
    }];
  }
  return modifiedFile;

run ();
```